# Working with 16:9 footage in FCE 4

Tags: video-editing, video, final-cut-express

I have 16:9 footage that I am working with in FCE 4. When I drop the footage into a sequence, the viewing area is 4:3. Then when I export it, I export it as 16:9, and it looks like stretched 4:3. Help! How do I fix this problem? Is there a setting that I need to change? I have already tried changing both the video clip settings and the sequence settings to anamorphic. That didn't help; it looked like stretched 4:3.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ***Anamorphic***.

To make a sequence anamorphic, right click on it and select ***Item Properties...*** In the resulting window, check ***Anamorphic*** (or the space where the check should be).
[image: FCE sequence settings]
To permanently change this setting for all future sequences, select ***DV-NTSC Anamorphic*** under ***Final Cut Express > Easy Setup...***

[image: fce easy setup]

Comment: That makes the footage look like stretched 4:3